# Sorting of 2 different sets of values of single row of a table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have the below table,

```
A             B            C
--------   ----------     -----------
Akhil      Kerala         0008 – 0030
Athul      Kerala         15
Basil      Delhi          0031 – 0059
Rahul      Chennai        32
Kishore    New York       0060 – 0090
Anoop      Mumbai         45
```

I have to sort the entries according to the column C, the sorted order of the column should be like,
15

32

45

0008 – 0030

0031 – 0059

0060 – 0090

Kindly advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix your question layout. It is very hard to read, and to understand the columns.

Comment: Please explain the ordering you want.

Comment: The values 15, 32, 45 belongs to one set and the others the 2nd set, I have to sort them separately in a single query. Is that possible?

Comment: I've just posted answer... but what database do you use? My solution is for Oracle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle SQL:

```
select t.*, 
  to_number(decode(instr(c,' '),5,null,c)) atr1,
  decode(instr(c,' '),5,c,null) atr2
from TEST_TAB t
order by atr1, atr2
```

If the table has many rows and the query will be frequently executed then you should add this index:

```
create index sort_idx on TEST_TAB (
  to_number(decode(instr(c,' '),5,null,c)),
  decode(instr(c,' '),5,c,null)
);
```

If you use e.g. MSSQL database then replace DECODE with CASE statement and INSTR with CHARINDEX.